Why does MPI_Sendrecv scale so much better than a separated MPI_Ssend/MPI_Recv call in my parallel C code?
I have written some very basic MPI code in C for image processing which iterates over N iterations and, in every iteration, completes a halo swap between processes using an MPI send/receive routine. I initially completed this halo swap using MPI_Ssend/MPI_Recv one after another separately, which resulted in a runtime of ~8 seconds on 64 processes over 100,000 iterations of the numerical routine. I then changed the messaging routine to MPI_Sendrecv in a combined call which resulted in a runtime of ~0.5 seconds, all other factors equal.
I then changed to 32 processes over 50,000 iterations. The separate scheme runtime now reduced to ~2.3 seconds, whereas the combined remained at ~0.5 seconds. I kept doing this and the results are in the table below



Processes
Iterations
Separate runtime (s)
Combined runtime (s)




64
100,000
8
0.50


32
50,000
2.32
0.49


16
25,000
0.86
0.43


8
12,500
0.48
0.41


4
6,250
0.39
0.37


2
3,125
0.38
0.37



So, we see that the weak scaling of the combined runtime is excellent, whereas for some reason the separate scaling is much worse. Does anyone know why this is?
The code is as follows:
        // Combined send receive approach
        MPI_Sendrecv(&old[Nx_mpi][1], Ny_mpi, MPI_DOUBLE, right, 1, 
           &old[0][1],  Ny_mpi, MPI_DOUBLE, left, 1,
           cart_comm, &statusArray[0]);

        MPI_Sendrecv(&old[1][1],    Ny_mpi, MPI_DOUBLE, left, 2, 
           &old[Nx_mpi+1][1], Ny_mpi, MPI_DOUBLE, right, 2,
           cart_comm, &statusArray[1]);

        // Seperate sends and receives approach
        MPI_Ssend(&old[Nx_mpi][1], Ny_mpi, MPI_DOUBLE, right, 1, cart_comm);
        MPI_Recv(&old[0][1],  Ny_mpi, MPI_DOUBLE, left, 1, cart_comm, &statusArray[0]);

        MPI_Ssend(&old[1][1], Ny_mpi, MPI_DOUBLE, left, 2, cart_comm);
        MPI_Recv(&old[Nx_mpi+1][1],  Ny_mpi, MPI_DOUBLE, right, 2, cart_comm, &statusArray[0]);

where cart_comm is a 1D Cartesian topology I created. Obviously, one of the options is commented out to actually run the program. This code is running on the ARCHER2 HPC unit which uses Cray MPI and GCC compiler. The code is compiled with no optimisation flags.

Assuming it does not deadlock, the second approach implicitly serializes communications, but the first one, all communications happen concurrently. If applicable, use neighbor collectives for optimal performances.

"The code is compiled with no optimisation flags" You didn't ask the compiler to produce fast code, so why are you measuring how fast the code is? Any such measurement is meaningless. It's like measuring how fast a car goes 0 to 100, but without pressing the gas pedal.

You miss the point. The issue here is the difference of behavior at scale, not the absolute performance.

@GillesGouaillardet If two numbers are meaningless, their ratio is also meaningless. How do you know the real values are above the noise floor in any of these measurements?

First, with compiler flags you might decrease computation time. That makes the code even more communication bound, and hence increase the time difference (ratio) between both communication schemes. Second, with 64 processes the elspased time jumps from 0.5 to 8 seconds, noise is hence irrelevant here.

Since your code does not deadlock, I assume that you use the cart comm without periodic boundary. Since you use ssend, the send can only complete once the matching send is posted. Without periodic boundary, the last rank sends to proc_null which is a noop. Therefore all communication per phase is sequential

matching receive

@n.m.couldbeanAI Sorry but I think you are wrong here - the point is in comparison between the two methods. There is a significant speed difference in the runtime of the two methods regardless of whether O1, O2, O3, or no optimisation is used. I can show you these results if you want? Would that help dispel your dissatisfaction with my question?Why do so many people comment on stack overflow with no helpful advice but merely to (wrongly) nitpick questions? I will never understand.

@GillesGouaillardet Joachim Thanks for the comments! I understand this and believe it is exactly what I am doing wrong - it's the proc_null resulting from use of Cartesian topology and the speed results show this, so the code is essentially serialised for the separate calls case. Question resolved.

It is entirely possible that in this particular case optimisations don't matter, but proving it is additional work you don't really need to bother with. Just always turn the optimisations on when you benchmark anything. That's the norm anyway.

You failed to understand the issue that is being discussed, and that optimization flags can only make a program more communication bound.

@ArthurScott Even code that should be similar could be wildly different without any optimizations. Building without optimizations isn't a fixed x% worse in all cases, comparing results without optimizations is meaningless.

@ThomasJager you also missed the point, read the previous comments.

@GillesGouaillardet Optimizations make differences meaningful. Disabling them will suppress or confuse the real effects. The point being made is that disabling optimizations is bad for comparing performance. If optimizations make the program more communication-bound, that's a good thing for comparing communication performance.

@ThomasJager Right, but the "fixed x% worse" is meaningless in this case since absolute performance was never being measured. I wasn't trying to figure out how fast my code could be run, I was simply trying to figure out why A ran less quickly than B, which was a parallelization/MPI issue not an optimisation one. I appreciate the advice re optimisation, however it was not relevant here.

@ThomasJager changing the communication pattern increases the elapsed time from 0.5 to 8 seconds. Optimization flags are irrelevant here.
